# Keeping a reference to gl in GLSurfaceView::onSurfaceCreated?

Tags: android, opengl-es, glsurfaceview

Is it safe to keep a reference to the GL10 gl parameter when GLSurfaceView::onSurfaceCreated is called?

I'd like to initialize textures at some point later than the onSurfaceCreated but I don't know now, so I wondered if just keeping a reference to it is ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that is generally a bad idea. You can bind textures in GLSurfaceView.Renderer::onDrawFrame.

Comment: Do you have any references that explains why it's a bad idea?

Comment: http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Creating_an_OpenGL_Context#Create_the_Context


The gl context is specific to a thread. So you don't want to use it in any other thread other than the GL thread in Android.